# Help with differential problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equatorial radius of the earth is approximately 6370 kilometers. Suppose that a wire is wrapped tightly around the earth's equator. Use differentials to determine approximately how much this wire must be lengthened if it is to be strung all the way around the earth on poles 1 meter about the ground.

I'm also not sure of what it looks like so it would be helpful if you could describe / show a diagram and if there were other ways of solving this without using differentials. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we assume that the wire essentially forms a circle (which is close to true if the poles are not ridiculously far apart), you can use the formula for the circumference of a circle. Old radius is $6370000$, new radius $6370001$. But they asked you to use differentials. The difference will be $(2\pi)(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the length of the wire in kilometers, $\ell$, as a function of the elevation (in kilometers as well) of the poles, $h$. We are interested in the increase $\Delta \ell=\ell(0.001)-\ell(0)$. The idea is to use the differential approximation

$$\Delta \ell \approx \ell'(0)  \Delta h$$

We already know that $\Delta h=0.001-0=0.001$, so we are left with finding $\ell'(0)$. In order to do that, we need a formula for $\ell(h)$ for general $h$: In that case we are talking about a circle with radius equal to that of the Earth's (6370 km) $+$ height of the poles ($h$). The circumference of that circle is $\ell(h)=2 \pi(6730+h)$. From here it is easy to find that $\ell'(0)=2 \pi$, and plugging this into the differential we find $$\Delta \ell \approx 2 \pi \times 0.001 \approx 0.006 \text{ km}.$$